# Confusing behavior of LQR control that strongly depends on system output (with odes solved by NDSolve)

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

I am implementing a LQR control of a 3-floors structure.

Firstly, I obtained a reasonable result with my first code (`Code 1` as shown below). In this code, the output mainly contains the displacements of three floors.

In my second code (`Code 2` as shown below), If I use a different output which includes mainly accelerations of floors, Mathematica will spit out error of “General"::" munfl”. Thanks to Suba Thomas’s help, I have noted that if I want output acceleration, state variables may change. I think I have used a right state variable in my second code.

Another confusing thing is that my second code gives different result (see figure below) even if I used that same output as in the first code.

so, my questions are:

1. Why my second code gives completely different results even if
   the same output has been used?
2. In my second code, how can I make Mathematica successfully solve it, if I use a output that different from the output in Code 1? Eventually,I only want the accelerations to be the output.

The data file "elcentro_NS.dat" used in my codes can be download from http://www.vibrationdata.com/elcentro.htm.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks :)

**`Code 1:` (gives reasonable results)**

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
SetOptions[Plot, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Evaluated -> True, Frame -> True ];

txgDat = Cases[ 
   Import["elcentro_NS.dat", "Data"], {x1_, x2_} :> {x1, 9.8 x2}];
tDat = txgDat[[All, 1]];
tend = Max[tDat];
xg = Interpolation[txgDat][t];
xgMax = Max[Abs@txgDat[[All, 2]]];
pNmax = xgMax/1000;
mNmax = xgMax/1000;

w = 0.1;
v = 0.01;
pDat = {tDat, 
    pNmax RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[w]], 
      Length[tDat]]}\[Transpose];
mDat = {tDat, 
    mNmax RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[v]], 
      Length[tDat]]}\[Transpose];
pNoise = Interpolation[pDat][t];
mNoise = Interpolation[mDat][t];
(* -- m, k symbolic matrix for finding correct state ------ *)
\
(*m={{Subscript[\[ScriptM], 1],0,0},{0,Subscript[\[ScriptM], \
2],0},{0,0,Subscript[\[ScriptM], 3]}};
k=Array[Subscript[\[ScriptK], #1,#2]&,{3,3}];
c=Array[Subscript[\[ScriptC], #1,#2]&,{3,3}];*)
(* \
----------------------------------------------------- *)

(* -------------- m, k numerical matrix ----------------- *)

m = {{m1, 0, 0}, {0, m2, 0}, {0, 0, m3}};
k = {{k1 + k2, -k2, 0}, {-k2, k2 + k3, -k3}, {0, -k3, k3}};
m1 = m2 = m3 = 4 10^5;
k1 = k2 = k3 = 2 10^8;
\[Zeta]1 = \[Zeta]2 = 5/100;
\[Omega]sol = \[Omega] /. 
   NSolve[{Det[k - \[Omega]^2 m] == 0, \[Omega] > 0}, \[Omega]];
{\[Omega]1, \[Omega]2} = \[Omega]sol[[1 ;; 2]];
\[Alpha]c = (
  2 \[Omega]1 \[Omega]2 (\[Zeta]1 \[Omega]2 - \[Zeta]2 \[Omega]1))/(\
\[Omega]2^2 - \[Omega]1^2);
\[Beta]c = (
  2 (\[Zeta]2 \[Omega]2 - \[Zeta]1 \[Omega]1))/(\[Omega]2^2 - \
\[Omega]1^2);
c = \[Alpha]c m + \[Beta]c k; c/10^6;
(* ---------------------------------------------------- *)

bs = {{1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1}};
\[CapitalLambda] = {{1, 1, 1}}\[Transpose];

uf = {uf1[t], uf2[t], uf3[t]};(*反馈输入*)

ue = {ue1[t], ue2[t], ue3[t]};

pN = {pN1[t], pN2[t], pN3[t]};

mN = {mN1[t], mN2[t], mN3[t]};

u = Flatten@{uf, ue, pN, mN};

eq = Flatten[
     m.{x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]} + c.{x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]} + 
      k.{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}] == 
    Flatten[-m.ue + bs.uf - m.\[CapitalLambda] pN] // Thread;

\[DoubleStruckY] = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]} + ue + mN;
\[DoubleStruckZ] = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]};

ss = StateSpaceModel[eq, \[DoubleStruckZ], u, \[DoubleStruckY], t, 
   SystemsModelLabels -> {ToString /@ u, ToString /@ y, 
     ToString /@ z}];

zUncontrol = 
  StateResponse[
    ss, {0, 0, 0, xg, xg, xg, pNoise, pNoise, pNoise, mNoise, mNoise, 
     mNoise}, {t, 0, tend}][[1 ;; 3]];
(*Grid@{Table[Plot[zUncontrol\[LeftDoubleBracket]i\
\[RightDoubleBracket],{t,0,tend},PlotTheme\[Rule]"Web"],{i,3}]}*)

\[Alpha] = 50; \[Beta] = 5 10^-6;
qMatrix = \[Alpha] ArrayFlatten[{{k, 0}, {0, 
      m}}](*IdentityMatrix[6]*);
rMatrix = \[Beta] IdentityMatrix[3];
kLQR = LQRegulatorGains[{ss, {1, 2, 3}}, {qMatrix, rMatrix}];
Flqr = -kLQR.\[DoubleStruckZ];
zLQRode = NDSolveValue[
   {eq /.
      {uf1[t] -> Flqr[[1]], uf2[t] -> Flqr[[2]], 
       uf3[t] -> Flqr[[3]],
       ue1[t] -> xg, ue2[t] -> xg, ue3[t] -> xg,
       pN1[t] -> pNoise, pN2[t] -> pNoise, pN3[t] -> pNoise,
       mN1[t] -> mNoise, mN2[t] -> mNoise, mN3[t] -> mNoise} // 
     Simplify, 
    x1[0] == x2[0] == x3[0] == x1'[0] == x2'[0] == x3'[0] == 0}, {x1[
     t], x2[t], x3[t]}, {t, 0, tend}];
(*Grid@{Table[Plot[zLQRode\[LeftDoubleBracket]i\[RightDoubleBracket],{\
t,0,30},PlotTheme\[Rule]"Web"],{i,3}]}*)

Table[Plot[{zUncontrol[[i]], zLQRode[[i]], PlotTheme -> "Web"}, {t, 0,
    tend}], {i, 3}]
```

**`Code 2:` (fails to give any result or wrong result if the same out as in Code 1 used)**

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
SetOptions[Plot, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Evaluated -> True, Frame -> True ];

txgDat = Cases[ 
   Import["elcentro_NS.dat", "Data"], {x1_, x2_} :> {x1, 9.8 x2}];
tDat = txgDat[[All, 1]];
tend = Max[tDat];
xg = Interpolation[txgDat][t];
xgMax = Max[Abs@txgDat[[All, 2]]];
pNmax = xgMax/1000;
mNmax = xgMax/1000;

w = 0.1;
v = 0.01;
pDat = {tDat, 
    pNmax RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[w]], 
      Length[tDat]]}\[Transpose];
mDat = {tDat, 
    mNmax RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[v]], 
      Length[tDat]]}\[Transpose];
pNoise = Interpolation[pDat][t];
mNoise = Interpolation[mDat][t];
Plot[{pNoise, mNoise}, {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Evaluated -> True];
(* -- m, k symbolic matrix for finding correct state ------ *)
\
(*m={{Subscript[\[ScriptM], 1],0,0},{0,Subscript[\[ScriptM], \
2],0},{0,0,Subscript[\[ScriptM], 3]}};
k=Array[Subscript[\[ScriptK], #1,#2]&,{3,3}];
c=Array[Subscript[\[ScriptC], #1,#2]&,{3,3}];*)
(* \
----------------------------------------------------- *)

(* -------------- m, k numerical matrix ----------------- *)

m = {{m1, 0, 0}, {0, m2, 0}, {0, 0, m3}};
k = {{k1 + k2, -k2, 0}, {-k2, k2 + k3, -k3}, {0, -k3, k3}};
m1 = m2 = m3 = 4 10^5;
k1 = k2 = k3 = 2 10^8;
\[Zeta]1 = \[Zeta]2 = 5/100;
\[Omega]sol = \[Omega] /. 
   NSolve[{Det[k - \[Omega]^2 m] == 0, \[Omega] > 0}, \[Omega]];
{\[Omega]1, \[Omega]2} = \[Omega]sol[[1 ;; 2]];
\[Alpha]c = (
  2 \[Omega]1 \[Omega]2 (\[Zeta]1 \[Omega]2 - \[Zeta]2 \[Omega]1))/(\
\[Omega]2^2 - \[Omega]1^2);
\[Beta]c = (
  2 (\[Zeta]2 \[Omega]2 - \[Zeta]1 \[Omega]1))/(\[Omega]2^2 - \
\[Omega]1^2);
c = \[Alpha]c m + \[Beta]c k; c/10^6;
(* ---------------------------------------------------- *)

bs = {{1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1}};
\[CapitalLambda] = {{1, 1, 1}}\[Transpose];


uf = {uf1[t], uf2[t], uf3[t]};

ue = {ue1[t], ue2[t], ue3[t]};

pN = {pN1[t], pN2[t], pN3[t]};

mN = {mN1[t], mN2[t], mN3[t]};

u = Flatten@{uf, ue, pN, mN};

eq = Flatten[
     m.{x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]} + c.{x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]} + 
      k.{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}] == 
    Flatten[-m.ue + bs.uf - m.\[CapitalLambda] pN] // Thread;

y = {x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]} + ue + 
   mN;(* with this y, error of "General::munfl" generates *)
\
(*y={x1[t],x2[t],x3[t]}+ue+mN;*)               (* with this y, wrong \
result generates *)

z = {x3'[t], x3[t], x2'[t], x2[t], x1'[t], x1[t]};
(* state changed from descriptor ssm to a standard ssm *)

ss = StateSpaceModel[eq, z, u, y, t, 
   SystemsModelLabels -> {ToString /@ u, ToString /@ y, 
     ToString /@ z}];

zUncontrol = 
  StateResponse[
    ss, {0, 0, 0, xg, xg, xg, pNoise, pNoise, pNoise, mNoise, mNoise, 
     mNoise}, {t, 0, tend}][[{6, 4, 2}]];
(*Grid@{Table[Plot[zUncontrol\[LeftDoubleBracket]i\
\[RightDoubleBracket],{t,0,tend},PlotTheme\[Rule]"Web"],{i,3}]}*)


\[Alpha] = 50; \[Beta] = 5 10^-6;
qMatrix = \[Alpha] ArrayFlatten[{{k, 0}, {0, 
      m}}](*IdentityMatrix[6]*);
rMatrix = \[Beta] IdentityMatrix[3];
kLQR = LQRegulatorGains[{ss, {1, 2, 3}}, {qMatrix, rMatrix}];
Flqr = -kLQR.z;
zLQRode = NDSolveValue[
   {eq /.
      {uf1[t] -> Flqr[[1]], uf2[t] -> Flqr[[2]], 
       uf3[t] -> Flqr[[3]],
       ue1[t] -> xg, ue2[t] -> xg, ue3[t] -> xg,
       pN1[t] -> pNoise, pN2[t] -> pNoise, pN3[t] -> pNoise,
       mN1[t] -> mNoise, mN2[t] -> mNoise, mN3[t] -> mNoise} // 
     Simplify, 
    x1[0] == x2[0] == x3[0] == x1'[0] == x2'[0] == x3'[0] == 0}, {x1[
     t], x2[t], x3[t]}, {t, 0, tend}];
(*Grid@{Table[Plot[zLQRode\[LeftDoubleBracket]i\[RightDoubleBracket],{\
t,0,30},PlotTheme\[Rule]"Web"],{i,3}]}*)

Table[Plot[{zUncontrol[[i]], zLQRode[[i]]}, {t, 0, tend}], {i, 3}]
```

[image: result of Code 1]

[image: unresonalbe result of Code 2]

[image: Code 2 generates error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are setting up the final ODEs incorrectly. I did not check, but using built-in functions to do it works fine.

After computing `eq`

```
y = {x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]} + ue + mN;
```

Then

```
z = {x3'[t], x3[t], x2'[t], x2[t], x1'[t], x1[t]};

ss = StateSpaceModel[eq, z, u, y, t, SystemsModelLabels -> {ToString /@ u, ToString /@ y, ToString /@ z}];

ainps = Flatten[Table[#, {3}] & /@ {0, xg, pNoise, mNoise}];
zUncontrol = OutputResponse[ss, ainps, {t, 0, tend}];
```

Compute the feedback gains

```
α = 50; β = 5 10^-6;
qMatrix = α ArrayFlatten[{{k, 0}, {0, m}}](*IdentityMatrix[6]*);
rMatrix = β IdentityMatrix[3];
kLQR = LQRegulatorGains[{ss, {1, 2, 3}}, {qMatrix, rMatrix}];
```

Compute the closed-loop system

```
csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[ss, kLQR, All, {1, 2, 3}];
```

Simulate

```
zLQRode = OutputResponse[csys, ainps, {t, 0, tend}];
```

And plot the results

```
Table[Plot[{zUncontrol[[i]], zLQRode[[i]]}, {t, 0, tend}], {i, 3}]
```

> [image]

Comment: @ Suba Thomas, thanks! You always give great insight into control problems. Please let's me think more about your answer and my problem before response to your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed, the problem is my odes are wrong. Thanks :)